# r sum all columns based on one value

Tags: r, dplyr

Got a df:

```
ID   Val1    Val2    Val3  
A    1        1       1
A    1        1       1
A    1        1       1
B    0        0       1
```

I want to take the sum of all the columns, based on a unique ID value. Like this:

```
ID   Val1    Val2    Val3     
A     3       3       3
B     0       0       1
```

I tried:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum()))
```

Anyone have an advice about what I' m doing wrong? I prefer a dplyr approach (if possible).

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(sum)` ?

Comment: The question is not merely a typographical issue, and highlights a potentially confusing aspect of the R language, in that functions can be invoked both with and without parentheses. In many cases, this difference has no effect (both `count` and `count()` will work as part of a dplyr chain). But in certain cases, the presence of parenthesis makes the difference between "call the function" versus "pass the function as an argument", as explained in the answer below.

Comment: Why load a package? `aggregate(. ~ ID, df, sum)` does it. Find simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the parentheses after `sum`, i.e., your code should read:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Typing `sum()` in this case *calls* the function, whereas passing just the name of the function sends it to be used by `summarise_all`. It's the difference between saying "use this function here and now," versus, "pass the function, as a parameter, to some other function". Similarly, typing, `?sum` will bring you the documentation for the function, but `?sum()` is invalid.

Comment: Ah, I was so close. This is the answer that I was looking for! TY.

Answer (score 0):

Edited*:

I don't know a solution using `dplyr`, but I do another solution using `plyr`, if interested.

You have:

```
   df=data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","B"), Val1=c(1,1,1,0), Val2=c(1,1,1,0),Val3=c(1,1,1,1))

> df
  id Val1 Val2 Val3
1  A    1    1    1
2  A    1    1    1
3  A    1    1    1
4  B    0    0    1
```

Using the plyr libray

```
> library(plyr)

> ddply(df,.(id),summarize,Val1=sum(Val1),Val2=sum(Val2),Val3=sum(Val3))
```

Output:

```
  id Val1 Val2 Val3
1  A    3    3    3
2  B    0    0    1
```

Comment: No problem, it's generally fine and accepted to post answers using different methods. I just found the wording a little surprising. I'll delete my comment